# how to optimize query that runs in foreach loop

Tags: php, sql, optimization, query-optimization, laravel-5.6

I have written query but it is taking 10 secs of time so, I want to optimize the code. My code is:

```
foreach($arrActiveJobsList as $user_id => $arrData) {
    $userId = [$user_id];
    $objCollectJobs = collect($arrData);
    $arrJobs = $objCollectJobs->groupBy('status')->toArray();
    $JobSubmissionQry = \App\Models\Ats\JobSubmission::query();
    $JobSubmissionQry->where([['job_submissions.record_status','=',0], 
    ['job_submissions.submission_status','>',0]])->where('jobs.record_status','=',0)->whereIn('job_submissions.submitted_by',$userId)->Where('job_submissions.job_id','>',0)->WhereBetween(DB::raw('CAST(submission_at as date)'),[$startDate,$endDate]);

    $JobSubmissionQry->leftJoin('hire.jobs', function($join) {
    $join->on('jobs.id', '=', 'job_submissions.job_id');
  });              
   $total_sub_query = clone($JobSubmissionQry);             
   $total_sub_query->where(function ($total_sub_query)  {
    $total_sub_query->WhereNull('jobs.client')->orWhere('jobs.client','=','')->orWhere('jobs.client','=','0');
});
   $nInternalSubmissions = $total_sub_query->count();
  $total_user_submission_query = clone($JobSubmissionQry);                      
  $no_of_application_jobs = $total_user_submission_query->select('job_id','expected_pay')->get();
  $resume_sourced = \App\Models\Ats\Candidate::where([['record_status',0],['is_resource_candidate',0]])->whereIn('created_by',$userId)->WhereBetween(DB::raw('CAST(created_at as date)'),[$startDate,$endDate])->count();
     $nTotalInterivews = \App\Models\Ats\Interview::whereIn('interviews.created_by',$userId)->where('job_id','>',0)->WhereBetween(DB::raw('CAST(interview_date as date)'),[$startDate,$endDate])->count();

}
```

Comment: You may want to try posting this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the execution plan for any of these queries? It might tell you where to use indices. If you need any more help, share the query that takes the most time, the table definition, and sample data

Comment: Actually the code is working fine but the the problem is, it was tooking 10 secs to fetch the data